# Replace file share server with a new one

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, cifs

I have a server, used for applications, with the path:
**\\cifs_server\folder**

I have to move it to a new server : 
**\\cifs_server_new\folder**

(both folders has been synced).

What's the best method for doing that, with the smallest interrupt of service?

- Change all the application's paths to the share (which can be long, IIS with lot of virtual directories)
- In host file, create an entry "IP_OF_NEW_SERVER      cifs_server"  (but will AD authentication still work?
- Remove *cifs_server* from domain, rename *cifs_server_new* to *cifs_server* and join it to domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would copy the data across and use DNS to redirect your users to the new server. You can setup the server, test it and have it fully working, once you change DNS users will access your new server.

This way you do not need to change paths and shares etc since to the computer its the same IP as the old server.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that both servers will not have the same IP. But according to you, it will not be a problem? Will AD authentication work as well?
Applications don't use IP to access path, just the name.

Comment: people access your cifs server by //cifs_server/share. If you have dns setup, you will have a FQDN to that server. So by editing the A record ip address in your dns you are able resolve the domain name to a different IP. So in turn keeping \\cifs_server.